SwiftUI table - Using keyboard shortcuts on a context menu
I have a context menu on a table row, that works fine. Now I am trying to add a keyboard shortcut to it. I see it in the menu, but it never fires.
What am I missing?  I am using SwiftUI on macOS 13 as target.
Table(/* selection, sort order etc */) {
// table column definitions
}
rows: { 
  ForEach(data){ line in
    TableRow(line)
      .contextMenu {
        ContextMenuLabel(title: "some action", image: "some image") {
            // action
        }
        .keyboardShortcut("F")
      }
   }
}


Keyboard shortcuts like this are just kind of broken right now. See also this unanswered question. You can use onKeyPress like I did here for now.
